# source code snippets for creating a lookup table with insert, delete and search function

Tags: c, linux, algorithm, search, linked-list

I want to construct a table with linux C

each table entry has 3 fields:

1 ip/port pair, 2 a FIFO queue pointer, 3 a thread id

the first entry ip/port pair is also a key for search,

for this table, the functionality is:

```
1 insert entry:  insert(table* tb, entry* ent)
2 delete entry (by searching key) : delete(table* tb, key* k)  
3 search entry* get_entry(table* tb, key* k), which returns a entry* pointer.
```

in order to make the IP/PORT pari as a key, my idea for dealing with this pair is to convert the IP address into `u_int32_t` , and port to `u_int16_t`， and then make a `u_int64_t` integer `key = (port << 32)+ip`

my initial idea is to make linked list

```
typedef struct {
    u_int64_t ip_port_pair;
    struct queue* q;
    pthread_t pid;
} entry;
```

and in the linked list, each element is an entry* pointer. 
But in this way, the search is a bit troublesome, 
and if u_int64_t can't be used on 32-bit machine, I have to make a structure like:

```
typedef struct{
    u_int32_t ip;
    u_int16_t port;
    struct queue* q;
    pthread_t pid;
}
```

and make two items: ip and port as a key, then it is more troublesome.

are there any similar source codes/snippets that can satisfy my requirements?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to implement an associative array or a hash table.  Since you're using Linux, your easiest bet may be to use the [hash table functionality from glibc](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html).  There are many other hash table libraries available, such as [uthash](http://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/index.html), if glibc isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Just construct a binary search tree, like this

http://www.thelearningpoint.net/computer-science/trees/binary-search-trees---c-program-source-code-and-documentation